# How to develop with PhpStorm + Docker?

Tags: php, windows, docker, phpstorm

There's a lot info in the internet about docker's base operations: "how to pull image", "how to run/start container", but almost nothing about what to do next with it. How to develop?

For example, I pulled [linode/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/). Simple project is lying in `/var/www/example.com/public_html/`.
I launch: `docker run -p 80:80 -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash`, `service apache2 start`. Now, in my browser in `http://localhost` I see an index page of the project.

Now I want to edit/add/delete files in the project. Do this with *bash* and *nano* is insane, obviously. Therefore I want to use *PhpStorm*. And I cannot understand what to do.
What option should I choose to create a project?

- Web server is installed locally, source files are located under its document root.
- Web server is installed locally, source files are located elsewhere locally.
- Web server is on a remote host, files are accessible via network share or mounted drive.
- Web server is on a remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS.
- Source files are in a local directory, no Web server is yet configured.

it the first, then where shoud I get files? If "via FTP/SFTP/FTPS" - how to set up? I don't get it.

I know that *PhpStorm* has *Deployment - Docker* settings and I can configure it. That how it looks on my machine:

[Docker settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YjyA.jpg)

[Debug/Run configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG7eZ.jpg)

But it only gives an ability to start containers, connect to them via console. Shoulв I use it somehow?

[Docker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkqjH.jpg)

Please, explain me, what should I do? I would like to see the answers for *Windows* и *Linux* (if there is a difference, of course)

P.S. I use *Docker* on *Windows*. But in Settings it's switched to Linux containers.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp, copy the `docker-compose.yml` and build folder into your project. tweak the `build/httpd/vhosts` to your liking (add your host in your hosts file too), then use `docker-compose build`, and `docker-compoe up` to run it. Not sure about the PHPStorm stuff but you can dev away in storm and it works fine.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Yes, it may work. But the point is not to download another image, suitable for me, but the ability connecting to any image. For example, some employer will give me a link to an image. I will pull it and...what will I do next?)) this is my problem at the moment, I guess. But the information about docker-machine I will keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: i would create a new entry in docker-compose.yml, add the image, and link it to the other images that would need it